# Can the standard deviation of the Gaussian window in a Gabor filter be made infinitesimally small?

Tags: filters, digital-filters, gaussian, bandpass, gabor

My understanding is that the standard deviation of the Gaussian window in a Gabor filter dictates the temporal resolution.

Wouldn't it always be better then to make the window smaller, thus achieving a high temporal resolution of exactly when in the input signal the frequency of interest (equal to the frequency of the sinusoid in the Gabor Filter) occurs?

Comment: Sure, if you’re tracking a signal with known and very narrow bandwidth (a sinusoid with fixed frequency being as narrow as it gets). But if you’re interested in a broader bandwidth, then you need the analysis window to be at least long enough to hold a full period of the lower frequency of interest.

Answer (score 0):

If your gaussian window width goes to zero, you are, in essence, sampling the signal, $x(t)$, (that was multiplied by the complex exponential, $e^{j 2 \pi f_0 t}$, which always has a magnitude of 1) with a dirac impulse.  So the value, after integration, is equal to your instantaneous sample with a known complex phase attached to it.

The output of the Gabor filter will essentially be the output of a one-sided AM modulator.

$$ y(t) = x(t) \cdot e^{j 2 \pi f_0 t} $$